# Using Symfonys dump in production

Tags: php, symfony

I used the `dump` function within one of our applications and our client got used to it during development (tbh I didn't know that it won't work in prod). Now the application is going live which means no more `debug` mode - and no more `dump` function.

Is there any way to enable the `dump` function during prod?

Comment: A client who is used to dump()? That's a peculiar kind of client. And an awkward habit, I'd say.

Comment: In production won't work dump(). I suggest you var_dump() function.

Comment: Make another function using `if (function_exists('dump')) ...` and declare a `dump()` that uses `print_r()` or `var_dump()` or something. Also, some way to turn it off (maybe an admin switch in the session enables it?).

Comment: Using Symfony dump produces the simplest and most human friendly output that i've seen when rendering a JSON structure. Would love to see this in production too... Will try print_r i guess for now...

Answer (score 1):

Despite weird will of use `dump()` in production env...

If I am not mistaken `dump()` is from `DebugBundle` which is enabled only in `dev` and `test` env.

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    ];
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }
    }
    return $bundles;
}
```

As you can see above `DebugBundle` is registered only in previous mentioned envs. Probably moving it out of the `if` will allow you to use `dump()` in production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indeed add this line to AppKernel.php:

```php
 $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
```

But also change this boolean in app.php from false to true:

```php
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); // true is replacing false, in second argument here
```

Tested for Symfony 4.4 and works.

Answer (score 0):

Read Symfony documentation , function 'dump()' is part of 'VarDumper' component, it's a dev dependency, so if you want to use it in prod you need to install it as required dependency:

❌ $ composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper

✔ $ composer require symfony/var-dumper

- But I guess it's not a good practice use it in production, it could show sensitive information.